# Let $h:S_4 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be a group homomorphism. Prove that $h(x) =0$ for all $x \in S_4$

Tags: group-theory, order-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

This a 3 part question. I struggle working with $S_4$ but seem to understand the questions if $S_4$ was not the codomain.

1. Let $f:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow S_4$ be a group homomorphism such that $f(1)=(1243)$. Precisely describe im($f$) and ker($f$).
2. Let G be a group, and let $x \in G$ such that ord$(x)$ is finite. Let $K$ be another group and let $g:G \rightarrow K$ be a group homomorphism. Explain why ord(g($x$)) in $K$ is a divisor of ord($x$).
3. Now let $h:S_4 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be a group homomorphism. Prove that $h(x) =0$ for all $x \in S_4$.

Comment: For part 3, hint: Every element in $S_4$ has a finite order

Comment: For $\mathbb{Z}$ every element has an order of $\infty$. Thus every element of $S_4$ must be sent to zero because ord($h(x)$) is a divisor of ord($x$)?

Comment: The image of $h$ is a finite subgroup of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Sorry, brain cell shortage tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_4$ is the group of permutations of 4 elements. Let $*$ represent composition of two permutations.

Part 1:
Since identity must map to identity,
$$f(0)=()$$
$$f(1)=(1243)$$
$$f(2)=f(1+1) = f(1)*f(1) = (14)(23)$$
$$f(3)=f(2+1) = f(2)*f(1) = (1342)$$
$$f(4)=f(3+1) = f(3)*f(1) = ()$$
Let $n=4q+r$, where $0\le r<4$ and $n,q\in \Bbb Z$.
$$f(n) = f(4q+r) = f(4q)*f(r)=f(4)^q*f(r)=()^q*f(r)=f(r)$$

So $$Im(f)=\{(),(1243),(14)(23),(1342)\}$$
$$Ker(f)=\{4n|n\in \Bbb Z\}$$

Part 2:
Let $m=ord(x)$ and $n=ord(g(x))$ where $x \in G$. So, $x^m=1_G$:-

Since identity must map to identity,
$$g(1_G)=g(x^m)=(g(x))^m = 1_K$$
$$(g(x))^m = 1_K \implies m=nk $$
Thus n divides m.

Part 3:
Let $x \in S_4$ such that $|h(x)| = M$ is maximum. Then $h(x*x)=h(x)+h(x)=2h(x)$.
By assumption, $|h(x)|\ge|2h(x)|$. Therefore $|h(x)|=0$. Since maximum is zero, and $|h(x)|\ge0$, $h(t)=0$ for all $t\in S_4$.

Comment: In part 1, you mean $f(3) = f(2+1)$ and $f(4) = f(3+1)$, right?

Comment: @amrsa thanks,edited!